# How to Detach Chrome Browser from Chrome Driver (Selenium Web Driver C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use Selenium Web Driver in VS 2010 C# to open a Chrome browser, navigate to some web page and **then close the driver but keep the browser open**. I realize that I will have to manually close the browser afterwards and I'm okay with that.

So far I have:

```
DriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("chrome.detach",true);
m_driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
[m_driver does stuff like navigate page, double click stuff, etc]
[last line: try to close driver but not browser]
```

I have tried all the following as the last line

```
m_driver.Dispose(); // closes both browser and driver

m_driver.Close(); //closes just the browser and not the driver

m_driver.Quit(); // closes both browser and driver

service.Dispose(); // closes both browser and driver
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We can detach chrome instance from chromedriver using "detach" options.

Sample Code:

```
ChromeDriverService cdservice = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/path/to/chromedriver.exe"))
                .withLogFile(new File("/path/to/chromedriver.log"))
                .usingAnyFreePort().withVerbose(true).build();
cdservice.start();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("detach", true);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cdservice,options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

// Do not call driver.quit().. instead stop chromedriver service.
cdservice.stop();
```

Comment: I'm using Selenium.WebDriver version 2.48. "options.setExperimentalOption" does not exist.  Plus, are you sure that's C#?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible, that kind of separation does not exist.

Comment: Then why is it documented on the ChromeDriver website? - https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities (see "detach")

Comment: @JaySullivan because this answer was given when ChromeDriver was in it's infancy and could not support it (and may be the only one that does right now).

Comment: The funny thing is, even though ChromeDrive documents it, I've tested `detach` and found it not to work.  Hard to say if I'm just doing it wrong—so far haven't seen anyone else online claiming success.

Answer (score 0):

chromeservice.driver.close()

has worked for me in the past but in this case you may need to write some coding for a method.

Comment: maybe you can add a code snippet with a coding suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is posible a least in c# you need the next lines:

```
driverOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
driverOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Python) When I called the selenium .get() function, Chrome would open up and close shortly after. I found online the advice to use the following code to remedy this issue: It worked for me in Python3; MacOSX 12.3 Monterey; Chrome Version 105.0.5195.102

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/Users/<user_acct_name>/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/105.0.5195/chromedriver')