# Intellij closing browser when I manually stop execution

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I am  opening a browser session within my test. I have added a break point on a line where I need to do some validations on that browser screen manually for my scripting purpose. As soon as I manually stop the execution from Intellij, it closes the browser and I am not sure how to stop it from doing that. Any inputs??

code below to open the browser::

```
WebDriver driver;
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(data.BrowserUrl), data.DesiredCapabilities);
// maximize remote browser
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: How do you open the browser from your code?

Comment: When you put a break point and run in debug mode, the code will be executed until break point and then execution will be stopped automatically. Does it works like that in your case?

Comment: That's right, execution will be stopped untill I resume within the tool. But I need to stop Intellij at that momment, and if i try doing that it closes browser session which I want to keep opened.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have updated my problem statement with the code you asked for

Comment: Please explain "manually stop the execution from Intellij".

Comment: By manual stopping, I meant I don't resume my test execution and I press the stop button on Intellij to stop the execution so that I can use the current browser window.

Comment: You may need to detach the browser so that it doesn't close when the test process terminates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34738079/104891.