# Using detach to stop Edge Browser from being closed when Selenium program ends

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am using selenium through python to automate a task - open a webpage, enter some text, click a button.

Now, once this is done, I want the browser to stay open and all the python files, the edgedriver.exe cmd window, and any other process ran by the python script to close. I want the browser to be loaded like a normal browser that we load manually.

My query:

1. Can we stop the browser from closing when I close python program as well as the edgebrowser.exe? I have added this to my code, but this doesn't stop browser from closing once all other windows are closed.

code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Using the detach option, I may be able to keep browser running with python closed. But I also do not want the edgebrowser.exe command window on the screen. Can we do that?

2. Can we remove that line below the address line saying "Your browser is being controlled by an automation test software". I want the browser window to look like it does when we open it using the app/program shortcut.

Comment: I am not sure if detach works. Although [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528700/how-to-detach-chrome-browser-from-chrome-driver-selenium-web-driver-c) is about Chrome, but I think it could be extrapolated to Edge too.
Would this help for your 2nd query? [SO archive link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299282/how-to-remove-the-infobar-microsoft-edge-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test)

Comment: Don't `.quit()`/`.close()` the driver... problem solved.

Comment: @Anand Gautam Hey thanks for sharing those. Actually, I have created this question only after referring to those links. Sadly, detach is not working. When I close the driver window, the browser window closes too. And I am not able to open the browser window without opening the driver window.

If there's a way to open the browser without opening the driver window on screen (background is fine), or if there's a way to close the driver and convert the browser to a normal browser, that's what I need.

Comment: @JeffC I am not closing or quitting the driver. My concern is that when I run the python code, there are two windows that open - one actual browser and one browser driver service command like window. I do not want that black background window to load or show to the user.

Comment: Why are they downvoting the question with no plausible explanation? At least tell me what is it that the question needs?

Comment: @Meet Your question states that you are looking for a way to NOT close the browser window when the Selenium script ends. I stated not to quit/close the driver to prevent the browser window from closing. Your response to that is referring to not wanting a particular window to display??? I'm confused as to what you are actually asking. If you are trying to ask a new question, clarify what you are asking here and then create a new question for the second question.

Comment: You can refer to [this link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/8647#issuecomment-690590293) to hide the command window. The code only works on selenium version 4.0.0 or higher. To remove the line "Your browser is being controlled by an automation test software", you can try to add these lines of code: `edge_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")`
`edge_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)`
`edge_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])`.

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks for the response. Can you post this as an Answer instead? Your response is the correct answer and I'd like to appreciate it that way. Others here do not seem to understand the question no matter how many edits I do.

Comment: @Meet I'm glad to help. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to [this link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/8647#issuecomment-690590293) to hide the command window. The code only works on selenium version 4.0.0 or higher.

To remove the line "Your browser is being controlled by an automation test software", you can try to add these lines of code:

```
edge_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") 
edge_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False) 
edge_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
```